# Arrayformula with large function for multiple columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I was wondering if anyone had a method for finding the second or third largest numbers in a row across multiple columns using the large function in Google Sheets using an arrayformula to account for a automatically growing list.

Comment: The `large()` function is an aggregating function and cannot give row-by-row results in an array formula context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in the range `A2:F`, put this in cell `G2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  vlookup( 
    row(A2:F) & "µ" & { 0, 1, 2 }, 
    { 
      row(A2) + int(sequence(rows(A2:F) * columns(A2:F), 1, 0) / columns(A2:F)) 
      & "µ" & 
      mod(sequence(rows(A2:F) * columns(A2:F), 1, 0), columns(A2:F)), 
      sort(split(flatten(row(A2:F) & "µ" & A2:F), "µ"), 1, true, 2, false) 
    }, 
    3, 
    false 
  ) 
)
```

The formula returns three columns, with the largest value row-by-row in the first column, the second largest in the second, and the third largest in the third. Make space for the results by choosing **Insert > Column**.

It is a bit on the heavy side, so please delete any unneeded blank rows at the bottom of the sheet before applying.

Hat tip to [Ed (Ohio)](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/104844972?msgid=104993772).

Comment: Just saw that in the 3rd row the 3rd 4th and 5th highest numbers were counted and not the 3 highest numbers.
I am using 8 columns to search for the highest 3 numbers if that helps

Comment: If your data does not span columns `A2:F` but instead spans `A2:H`, replace `A2:F` in the formula with `A2:H`.

Comment: That fixed it and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for that