# Sorting columns within a row, alphabetically

Tags: google-sheets

I have let's say I have rows in the following order:

| SN | name1 | grade1 | name2 | grade2 | name3 | grade3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 97 | Bob | 90 | Carl | 80 |
| 2 | Bob | 80 | Alice | 100 | Carl | 95 |
| 3 | Alice | 100 | Carl | 80 | Bob | 90 |

Is there a way to keep the rows ordered 1 - 2 - 3, but alphabetize the columns by the student's names, while keeping the grade associated with each student?
Meaning, all rows will be in the format

```
SN | Alice | grade1 | Bob | grade2 | Carl | grade3 |
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: I concur with doubleunary: please share a link to a spreadsheet with *realistic* sample data (e.g., if you have first and last name in cells, use first and last dummy names, not just first, etc.). What you want can likely be accomplished via formula; but it is complex and, in my opinion, may go beyond what a free forum such as this is designed to offer (though it will be up to each individual volunteer contributor how much time they are willing to invest via the forum).

Comment: I'll assume you're no longer interested in help from the forum since you haven't responded with comment, a shared spreadsheet, or even acknowledging the work that volunteer contributor "doubleunary" did on your behalf over a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the content of each row horizontally, and independently of other rows, using the recipe at [Arrayformula with large function for multiple columns in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153806/269219).

But I think that it would probably make more sense to recast the data to a row-oriented layout. You can get a simple table with just three columns (SN, Name, Grade) like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
    query( 
      { 
        flatten( iferror( 
          vlookup( Grades!A1:A, Grades!A1:A, sign(sequence(1, columns(Grades!B1:G) / 2)), false ) 
        ) ), 
        flatten( filter( Grades!B1:G, not(isnumber(Grades!B2:G2)) ) ), 
        flatten( filter( Grades!B1:G, isnumber(Grades!B2:G2) ) ) 
      }, 
      "where Col1 is not null 
       and Col2 is not null 
       order by Col1, Col2", 
      1 
    ) 
)
```

This format is more conducive for further processing with additional `query()` or `filter()` formulas, pivot tables, and such.

In the event row 2 in data may contain blanks, use `flatten( { B1:B, D1:D, F1:F } )` and `flatten( { C1:C, E1:E, G1:G } )` instead of the two `flatten(filter())` expressions.

Assuming that the three-column data is in `Data!A1:C`, you can create a simple report that pivots names horizontally like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    Data!A1:C, 
    "select A, max(C) 
     where A is not null 
     group by A 
     pivot B", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```